# Objective-C, Typhoon, passing an Assembly as a parameter

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

In my application that uses Typhoon library, I've created an **AppAssembly** that is being initialized in **SceneDelegate** like this:

```
self.appAssembly        = [[AppAssembly new] activated];
```

my **appAssembly** looks like this

```
- (Person *)me;
- (Dog *)dog;
- (Cookie *)cookie;
- (DogInteractionVC *)dogVC;
- (HowManyCookiesVC *)howManyCookiesVC;
```

From **SceneDelegate** I want to transit to **dogVC**,
Then, from the **dogVC**, I want to transit to **howManyCookiesVC**

Calling the instance of **dogVC** from **SceneDelegate** is quite easy as I do have an access to it:

```
self.viewController     = [self.appAssembly dogVC];
```

I do not understand how to pass the very same **appAssembly** instance to a **dogVC** and then to **howManyCookiesVC**. When I try to create an instance of **AppAssembly** in the **dogVC**, I come across the issue that I believe is called **circular dependency**.

There is a guide on GitHub about injecting **Assembly** itself. So I created a property **appAssembly** in a **dogVC** of type **TyphoonComponentFactory**. Here is how my initializing method inside my **appAssembly** for a **dogVC** looks like:

```
- (DogInteractionVC *)dogVC {
   return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[DogInteractionVC class]
                         configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
      
      [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithPerson:)
                      parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
         
         [initializer injectParameterWith:[self me]];
      }];
      
      [definition injectProperty:@selector(appAssembly) with:self];
   }];
}
```

I think the part **injectProperty:@selector(appAssembly)** is wrong, but I spent a long time understanding that, and I am afraid that I cannot go any further than this without some help from the community. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Side note:
Dear community, I am very close to being blocked from posting, as my last posts have not been well received. I believe that question has everything that it needs. If I am wrong, please let me know before putting your thumbs down so I can understand my mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/appsquickly/typhoon-example/blob/master/PocketForecast/Assembly/PFApplicationAssembly.m  <-- In example here, you can see that CitiesListController (line53) has the assembly injected. This feature is documented here: https://github.com/appsquickly/typhoon/wiki/What-can-be-Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself

Comment: Hi Jakub. Provided some quick info in a comment, to hopefully get you started.  Will provide a full written answer when back at desk.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time. I've created a property **appAssembly** for my first VC **dogVC** and appropriate initializer. I've corrected a method in **appAssembly** based on an example, by adding `[initializer injectParameterWith:self];` and choosing the right selector `@selector(initWithPerson:assembly:)`. Sadly, now, when I want to reach some properties from **appAssembly** in my **dogVC**, whichever property I am going to choose, the app will crash. Ex.: `[self.appAssembly cookie].name);`. _'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TyphoonAssemblyAccessor cookie]: unrecognized selector_

Comment: Hey, I have managed to pass that issue with `[definition injectProperty:@selector(assembly)];` and NOT passing assembly directly through the dogVC's initializer.
But I started to realize that I think I am missing the point here. 
I would like to create one and the only instance of the **Person** class. Would it be appropriate to, inside my **appAssembly**, create a method that instantiates the Person, but then also stores it in **appAssembly**?

Comment: Little clarification about the question above. There is a short tutorial on how to use Typhoon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hm1CP6c49hY&list=PLhU81D62nv-Yd5jCW9LRjI4_AfI5NwJhe&index=3. At 6:05 of that video, the author says that Typhoon will create one and only instance of that class throughout the application. What I understood by that is, when I call `[self.appAssembly cookie]` for the second time throughout my code, Typhoon will automatically refer to that specific cookie. But my application just creates another instance. I may misunderstand due to my English level, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Jakub. Sorry for the delay. Yes you can use ` definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;` to get the same instance every time. I'll add an answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232857/discussion-between-jasper-blues-and-jakub-gawecki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dependency Injection:**

Typhoon helps to apply the dependency injection pattern - an object oriented software approach whereby:

- The key actors and their interactions with other core software components in a system a declared at the [composition root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

In this way:

- We can de-duplicate configuration of shared objects.
- We can have the benefits of singletons without overly tight coupling.

**Using Dependency Injection in a Mobile App:**

When we use dependency injection in a mobile app, we start at the app delegate to launch a view controller.

- The first controller will depend on some singleton services to do its job.
- We may then wish to transition from one view controller to another. We can load an 'object graph' consisting of the view controller and it dependencies.
- When the next controller is presented, we can release the current one.

**Factory Pattern:**

To transition from one controller to another we can use Typhoon as a factory for emitting built instances. The factory pattern allows us to:

- Obtain an instance (ie a view controller) with a mix of runtime and static dependencies.

So to transition from one view controller to another we can inject Typhoon assembly to be used as a factory to obtain the next view controller. To inject the assembly as a factory, docs [are here](https://github.com/appsquickly/typhoon/wiki/What-can-be-Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself).

**Scopes:**

Depending on navigation style, controllers will typically retained in memory as long as used and then released. Meanwhile services or other shared infrastructure will be shared.

- The default scope is `TyphoonScopeObjectGraph`
- To create a shared class use `definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton` as documented [here](https://github.com/appsquickly/typhoon/wiki/Scopes).

**Pilgrim:**

Typhoon is, at least in my opinion, the best and most flexible DI library for objective-C. Meanwhile, if you use Swift you might like to try simpler and better: [pilgrim.ph](https://pilgrim.ph)